# BackgroundWorker is currently busy and can not run multiple tasks concurrently

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am trying to iterate an array while using backgroundworker, I am sure it is just my syntax being incorrect, but I am constantly getting the error.  Can someone assist me with what to do to rectify this?

```
namespace Form1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker1 = new BackgroundWorker();
    public OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        backgroundWorker1.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_DoWork);
        backgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged);
    }
    private void btn_Two_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fd.Title = "Select The Text File To Open";
        fd.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";
        fd.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            TextFiles(sender);
        }
    }
    private void TextFiles(object sender)
    {
        IEnumerable<String> employeeNames = File.ReadLines(fd.FileName);
        foreach (string pgs in employeeNames)
        {
            employee = pgs;
            ProcessTables(employee, sender);
        }
    }
    private void ProcessTables(string employee, object sender)
    {
        sw.Restart();
        timer.Start();
        //This line is where the compiler throws the error
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();            
    }
    private void backgroundworker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
      progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
    private void backgroundworker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
      //Never hits this block so I will omit this code for time sake
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where are your background worker event methods?

Comment: @Lloyd -- see edits.  My code is not actually reaching those methods, it hits the RunWorkerAsync() and throws the error

Comment: You are calling the same backgrounder worker multiple times in the foreach loop. You could create multiple background workers (that would be a mess) or use multithreading which would be the proper way to solve this problem if you want to process files concurrently.

Comment: See this article on how to write a simple parallel for each loop: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ProcessTables` is called in a loop by `TextFiles`. So you're trying to restart a running `BackgroundWorker`.

How to solve this, depends on what you're actually trying to do (you could prepare a "todo list" for a single `BackgroundWorker`, use multiple `BackgroundWorker`s, use producer/consumer pattern).

Comment: I am trying to prepare a todo list before calling the background worker.  How would I re-write to only call the backgroundworker once?

Comment: Well, call RunWorkAsync after the loop - put all employees in a list and hand this list over to `DoWork` (see method overloads in MSDN).

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have called `BackgroundWorker` twice by clicking the `btn_Two`. You should disable button while BackgroundWorker is busy.

```
private void ProcessTables(string employee, object sender)
    {
        sw.Restart();
        timer.Start();
        btn_Two.Enable = false;
        backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();            
    }
```

And you should add backgroundWorker `Comleted` event handler where enable the button. Like this

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(
    object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    btn_Two.Enable = true;
}
```

Comment: I think the issue is that it hits TextFiles method then goes to ProcessTables, but if their are multiple elements in the array, it is going to try to hit ProcessTables multiple times thus trying to call backgroundworker multiple times.

Comment: Yeah, looks like. But disable your button any way ;)